# Cannot add item to cart when viewing item, but can from directory page

Tags: shopping-cart, cart, magento-1.9

Using magento, I customers cannot add items to cart when viewing that item.  However, when in the directory page that lists multiple items the "add to cart" button is there, and that works fine.  Shopping cart works fine all the way to end.

This is a second store hosted on the same server as the main store.  All products and add-to-cart works fine on main website.  Only this store does not work.  And, only when on the product page itself.
Using Magento 1.9

Website for reference:
http://www.oxidationtech.com/products.html

This is a new store I have created, so any issues that could arise from that could have created this?  Any suggestions?